# is it possible to calculate the distance across a circle from any given point within the circle on the Y axis

Tags: geometry, circles

I need to know A. if it is possible to calculate the distance across a circle (parallel to the x axis) from any point on the y axis within a circle, and B. what the equation would look like.

Better Explanation:
If I have a circle, and I know the diameter, is it possible to figure out how far across the two bounds of the circle are at any given point within the circle on the y-axis.

This is an image showing what I mean:

[image: Circle Image]

I know the diameter, and I know where the red 'x' is in the circle (x,y) is it possible to figure out the length of the red line that intersects the red 'x' within the circle.

Comment: If your circle center is $x_0,y_0$ and the radius is $R=d/2$, then the length of red line between intersection points with the circle is $2\sqrt{R^2-(y-y_0)^2}$, for $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2< R^2$. It could be easily figured out using Pythagoras theorem.

Comment: As an example, if the circle is centered at $(0,0)$ and has radius $1$, and if $0 < y_0 < 1$, then the length of the chord parallel to the $x$-axis that crosses the $y$-axis at $(0,y_0)$ will be $2\displaystyle \sqrt{1-(y_0)^2}.$

Comment: Ok, I see what you guys mean. I'll try it out, thanks!

Comment: It worked incredibly well, thank you both for your help!